# Unable to load the requested file in codeigniter on ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu

I want to email with template. for template   , I use :

```
    $data = array('activationlink'=>$activationLink);
    $ci = get_instance();
    $ci->load->library('parser');
    $body = $ci->parser->parse('template\member_activation_mail', $data, TRUE);
```

this code runs local server on windows. but When uploaded the ubuntu server   I get following error

Unable to load the requested file: template\member_activation_mail.php

Thanks your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you change the backward slash to a forward slash in your file path it may work. So change `'template\member_activation_mail'` to `'template/member_activation_mail'`. Windows will mostly work with either direction slash but Unix based systems like Ubuntu require forward slashes.